# Formatting dates when converting to list

Tags: r, date, summarize

I have a table like this:

| ID | Date | Status |
| --- | --- | --- |
| 101 | 2020-09-14 | 1 |
| 102 | 2020-09-14 | 1 |
| 103 | 2020-09-14 | 1 |
| 104 | 2020-09-14 | 2 |
| 105 | 2020-09-14 | 2 |
| 106 | 2020-09-14 | 2 |

But want a table like this:

| Status | ID | Date |
| --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | 101,102,103 | 2020-09-14, 2020-09-14, 2020-09-14 |
| 1 | 104,105,106 | 2020-09-14, 2020-09-14, 2020-09-14 |

Code that i'm currently using:

note: date is in format yyyy-mm-dd before running code.

```
g1 <- df1 %>% 
  mutate(Date = as.Date(Date, format = '%Y%m%d')) %>%
  group_by(status) %>% 
  summarise_at(c("ID", "Date"), list)
```

This seems to work except for the date in the new table is not in yyyy-mm-dd. For example, 2021-06-10 is converting to 18788.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

A possible solution:

```r
library(tidyverse)

df %>% 
  group_by(Status) %>% 
  summarise(ID = str_c(ID, collapse = ","), Date = str_c(Date, collapse = ","))

#> # A tibble: 2 × 3
#>   Status ID          Date                            
#>    <int> <chr>       <chr>                           
#> 1      1 101,102,103 2020-09-14,2020-09-14,2020-09-14
#> 2      2 104,105,106 2020-09-14,2020-09-14,2020-09-14
```

---

A more succinct alternative:

```r
library(tidyverse)

df %>% 
  group_by(Status) %>% 
  summarise(across(c(ID, Date), str_c, collapse = ","))

#> # A tibble: 2 × 3
#>   Status ID          Date                            
#>    <int> <chr>       <chr>                           
#> 1      1 101,102,103 2020-09-14,2020-09-14,2020-09-14
#> 2      2 104,105,106 2020-09-14,2020-09-14,2020-09-14
```

Comment: Thank you so much, this worked perfectly. Would you be able to explain what the code is doing in your example vs mine? Would love to understand it a little better.

Comment: You are welcome! First, there is no need to convert dates to date format. Second, when summarizing, I just concatenate the ID and then the dates. Moreover, `summarise_at` is superseded. And while you try to get a list, I try to get a concatenated string. I am going no to try to shorten my solution.

Comment: See my second solution, which is closer to your attempted solution.